# How do I access a variable inside a nested function from another function?

Tags: python, function

Let's say I have a code snippet like this :

```py
def z():
    def y():
        v = 10
def x():
```

and inside function `x` I want to access variable `v`. How do I do that in simplest way possible?

Comment: The short answer is: `You can't`. Longer answers depend on how `x, y, and z` are called.

Comment: it's not possible.. is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a complicated approach but kinda works. I wouldn't recommend using this in actual code though.

```py
def z():
    def y():
        y.v = 20
    y.v = 10
    return y

def x():
    y = z()

    print(y.v)
    # 10
    y()
    print(y.v)
    # 20

x()
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is 1 way

```
def z():
    def y():
        global v
        v = 10

    y()


def x():
    print(v)


z()
x()
```

**Note : you have to invoke y() at least one before invoking x**

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do that, however, to solve this, you can use a globally accessible variable like so:

```
globalVariable = 0
def z():
  def y():
    v = 10
    globalVariable = v
def x():
  #use globalVariable here
```

However do make sure you already called function y() before accessing x() so that you are getting the correct value you wanted.